# laravel job queue not working on fresh app

Tags: php, laravel

i have new project on `laravel9` and im trying to create new job and queue like this code
this is my route

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Jobs\Test_job;
use App\Services\AudioProcessor;
Route::get('/', function () {
    return Test_job::dispatch();
});
```

and this is my `Test_job`

```
<?php
namespace App\Jobs;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeUnique;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
class Test_job implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public function __construct()
    {

    }
    public function handle()
    {
       // anything here
    }
}
```

when i run it i get this error

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::setContent(): Argument #1 ($content) must be of type ?string, Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\PendingDispatch given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Response.php on line 72
```

i tried to delete the laravel and install it but nothing is run currectly
its fresh app but it didnot work

this is my env file

```
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
```

and this is my queue file

```
    'sync' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
    ],
```

thanks

Comment: You can't return a Dispatch. Just dispatch it and return something else

Comment: even if i didnot return anything i still get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) check if your queue.php file has this database entry under connections:

```
'connections' => [

        'sync' => [
            'driver' => 'sync',
        ],

        'database' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'jobs',
            'queue' => 'default',
            'retry_after' => 90,
            'after_commit' => true,
        ],
```

2.) check if you have a migration under database/migrations that include

```
public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('jobs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('queue')->index();
            $table->longText('payload');
            $table->unsignedTinyInteger('attempts');
            $table->unsignedInteger('reserved_at')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedInteger('available_at');
            $table->unsignedInteger('created_at');
        });
    }
```

if not, hit the following:

```
php artisan queue:table
```

3.) maybe, check this guide (not from me) if everything is as it should be:
https://www.ultimateakash.com/blog-details/IixDRGAKYAo=/How-To-Implement-Queue-In-Laravel-2022

Best of luck,
Mike